# Conditional Formatting - how to reference a cell itself?

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to write VBA code to set conditional formatting for a column, so that when the cell contains mix of lower-case and upper-case letter, fill the cell with yellow color.  Column number will be determined by variable c.  And last row number will be determined by variable last_row.

The following code didn't work as desired.  It looks like LCase(xlCellValue) always returns "1" instead of the cell content in lower case format.  Thus the condition becomes "CellValue <> 1", which didn't do what I wanted it to do.

```
c = 1
last_row = 10
Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(last_row, c)). _
  FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, LCase(xlCellValue)). _
  Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

So I guess I'll have to use xlExpression instead of xlCellValue.  But how shall I write the formula so it'll take variables c and last_row?  Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried seeing what conditional formatting looks like after running your code? Sometimes, I find it helpful to do that when trying to trouble shoot conditional formatting vba.

Comment: Yes, the code I wrote yields a condition of "CellValue <> 1".  That how I realized that LCase(CellValue) always returns 1, which I don't understand either.  :)

Comment: You're probably trying to get cells.value (or Range.Value) not CellValue

Comment: `xlCellValue` is a numeric constant with a value of `1`. `LCase(xlCellValue)` takes that constant, converts it to a string, and then converts that string to lowercase, which is a string with a value of `"1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
Sub test()
c = 1
last_row = 10
Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(last_row, c)). _
  FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=NOT(Exact(" & Cells(1, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ",Lower(" & Cells(1, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ")))"). _
  Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

I don't know if the comparison with the `xlCellValue, xlNotEqual` would be case-sensitive; however, Excel has a function `Exact` which **is** a case-sensitive comparison. I added a `Not` to cause the return from the formula to be true when the string is **not** all lower case. Since this is set-up using Excel Functions, I also replaced `Lcase` with `Lower`.

---

**Note:**

Using the logic you were following, if the entire string is upper-case, it also gets colored yellow. If you only want the conditioning when it's a mix of cases, you should use the below code instead:

```
Sub test()
c = 1
last_row = 10
Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(last_row, c)). _
  FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, , "=NOT(OR(Exact(" & Cells(1, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ",Lower(" & Cells(1, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ")),Exact(" & Cells(1, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ",Upper(" & Cells(1, c).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & "))))"). _
  Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  It worked.  I just couldn't figure out how to reference variable c in formula.  Now I understand that I should use the ".Address" property.

Comment: @Helloguys Glad I could help. Using Conditional Formatting with a formula can be a bit confusing; but basically, you want to input the formula as if you were only applying it to the first cell in the range; with cell references being fixed ($A$1) or not (A1) as you would if you were putting the formula in a cell, to fill by dragging. Hence, why I only technically used the address of the first cell in the range. Also, note that the `.Address` property defaults to fixed value ($A$1) unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the format condition to `[ActiveSheet.]Range([ActiveSheet.]Cells(1, c), [ActiveSheet.]Cells(last_row, c))` - you can extract that into a local variable:

```
Dim target As Range
Set target = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, c), ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, c))
```

And then use that variable to refer to the cell:

```
Dim fCondition As FormatCondition
Set fCondition = target.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlNotEqual, LCase$(target.Value))
```

---

> It looks like LCase(xlCellValue) always returns "1" instead of the cell content in lower case format.

That's because `xlCellValue` is a constant, with a value of `1`. `LCase(xlCellValue)` is therefore equivalent to `LCase(1)`, which will always only ever return `"1"`.

Comment: Mathieu, thank you for your help.  What does LCase$(target.Value) do?  Not sure if I got it right, but I got a "Type Mismatch" error.

Comment: Because taking the `.value` of a range returns an Array, whereas `LCase$()` expects a string.

Comment: @Patrick that's absolutely correct, ...that's what I get for coding in the answer box lol